# Typescript: Why is a type constraint not checked when a type parameter from a function is passed to a mapped type?

Tags: typescript, generics, typescript-generics, mapped-types

```
type SomeMappedType<T extends Record<string, any>> = {
  [K in keyof T]: T[K]
}


function myFunc<T extends SomeMappedType<T>>(myArg: T){

}

const y: SomeMappedType<object> = {foo: 'bar'}; // okay.  makes sense.
const z: SomeMappedType<{foo: 'bar'}> = {foo: 'bar'}; // okay.  makes sense.

//@ts-expect-error
const x: SomeMappedType<string> = {foo: 'bar'}; // This error makes sense. `string` type parameter violates the Record<string, any> constraint

myFunc<string>('hey');  // Why is `string` not checked against the `Record<string,any>` constraint in this context ??
```

Why is TS unable to detect that my function `myFunc` is violating its type constraint?  `SomeMappedType` has a constraint of `Record<string, any>` which `string` violates.  If I pass `string` directly into `SomeMappedType` I get an error as expected.  However, when I specify `string` as a type parameter for `myFunc<T>` which has a constraint of `SomeMappedType<T>` I do not get an error!  Why does `myFunc<string>('blah');` not violate its type constraint of `SomeMappedType<string>` ???;

[TSPlayground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/LAKALgngDgpgBAZQPYFsYFkCGVYBMAq0MAPPnDAB5gwB2uAznAEowDGSATrsfWBwJY0A5gBo4mGhAB8UuAF44Ab1Bw4AbQDScQXADWMCEgBmcfAF0AXKc1nQAX1CgjAVxqsw-JDTgoIAMVdWUnIqWgZEVAxsPEJYUhkACl8AQQ4hK3wASmUQe0cQdhpeOAorZDQsHBgCIh4%20QSFZBUUjJCQrAHIAI0wODrsAbjgAemHTAAt%20RhgODk4fTH1GeloVgDo4AANeAWFNuEhYOChezDRqDjgAN08AG0xqRjBx%20BZ2Ljrd0XFJWUKdzCCMD5XwBNyfBpSBIdF4QDqZIYjMYAdXGEG0jG29T2cBoSDAcFYL1Y%20lw4iEgKKBOe8E2b043B2DREEmk%200KYABQO03meU0JXmoVDgAH4RfkJbkQEA)

Comment: Feels like a TS bug to me, but I haven't found an obviously relevant [GitHub issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues).  Someone (you?) might want to file a (properly formatted) issue asking what's going on here.

Comment: You can't actually use the generic type within the extends.
You're using a generic type of `T extends SomeMappedType<T>`. When you would resolve this type, you would replace the `T` with `SomeMappedType<T>` as T extends from it, so you would have a type like this `SomeMappedType<SomeMappedType<T>>`. There is still a T inside, which you again will replace,.. Doing so, you would actually get in loop.
So, Typescript is actually unable to resolve this generic type a you defined. Short, you shouldn't use a generic with its extends. Typescript should also inform you about it, which isn't.

Comment: @W.S.  That's not really accurate; you can certainly have recursive type constraints. Constraints don't get resolved the way you're implying.  Something of the form `T extends F<T>` is fine because `T` is not inferred from `F<T>`.  Instead, the compiler infers `T` from elsewhere and then just needs to *check* that `T extends F<T>` holds for the given `T`.  [For example](https://tsplay.dev/W4OLKm).

Comment: @jcalz Thanks so much for the response! I created a new [GitHub issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/49302).